# update query to update the sorting order number in a column ORDER_NUM same table, sorted by date for each FK_ID

Tags: oracle11g, sql-update

```
Table1
=============================
FK_ID           DATE            NAME            ORDER_NUM
1               D1              N1              NULL
1               D2              N2              NULL
1               D3              N3              NULL
1               D4              N4              NULL
2               D5              N7              NULL
2               D2              N8              NULL
2               D3              N9              NULL
```

Result

```
Table1
=============================
FK_ID           DATE            NAME            ORDER_NUM
1               D1              N1              1
1               D2              N2              2
1               D3              N3              3
1               D4              N4              4
2               D1              N7              1
2               D2              N8              2
2               D3              N9              3
```

I want to write an update query in oracle which will update the sorting order number in same table column called as ORDER_NUM sorted by date for each FK_ID

Answer (score 0):

```
merge into table1
using (
  select rowid as rid, 
         row_number() over (partition by fk_id order by date) as rn
  from table1
) t on (t.rid = table1.rowid) 
when matched then update
  set order_num = rn;
```

I used `rowid` as a "PK replacement" because your example doesn't contain columns that seem to be the primary key of that table.

<sup>Btw: `date` is  a horrible name for a column, I hope it's not the real one</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much... it worked fine... and yes it is not the real column name :)